# Propagate Line Item Properties to Checkout page

Tags: shopify

Line Item Properties (http://wiki.shopify.com/Line_Item_Properties) provides a nice way for merchants to collect extra info for line items. It's possible to edit the cart template and the email templates so that the line item properties show in /cart and order confirmation emails.

My question is - is there any way to access those properties and have them show on the checkout page? The checkout page template is not available for editing. The page becomes confusing for the customer, as properties they've selected on their products no longer show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The reason is that you can collect almost anything in line item properties and cart attributes. Since merchants cannot control pages 1 and 2 of checkout, they cannot control any scripting there. Hence it would be up to Shopify to render those. Meaning some shops might be rendering poorly in the checkout, since the code would have to be generic.

For years I have just explained to my clients, the merchants, that since these attributes were clear in the cart prior to checkout, and that since they are included in the emails... it's not a big deal, but you obviously feel differently... Perhaps one day the checkout will render with some scripting added from the merchant, for the display of line items... that would be swell.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Checkout pages 1 & 2 should be considered a black box.

Comment: Thanks guys. I strongly suspected as much, but I thought there'd be no harm in double-checking.